# Unable to download libtiff4_3.9.5-2ubuntu1.3_i386.deb and libcups2_1.5.3-0ubuntu4_i386.deb

Tags: installation, steam

For some reason, I can't seem to download `Steam` `beta` on Ubuntu xx.xx. It shows the following error messages:

```
Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/c/cups/libcups2_1.5.3-0ubuntu4_i386.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]

Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/t/tiff/libtiff4_3.9.5-2ubuntu1.3_i386.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
```

Though I can still connect to the Internet and download other packages.

Is the server down?

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using? If it is older than 11.04 other than 10.04 then supports have died and you need to upgrade to a higher version of Ubuntu. And please refer to [this](http://askubuntu.com/faq#howtoask) before asking questions over here, it may help you get answers faster.

Answer (score 0):

Run `sudo apt-get update` again.

If that doesn't work, just wait. You might have caught something in the middle of mirroring.